Telethon client .session + socks5 proxy quick deauthorization
I have a valid .session + .json files pair representing Telegram account session.
Code below initializes a Telethon client using valid socks5 proxy having same GEO as client telegram account from a .session file.
from python_socks import ProxyType
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import rpcerrorlist
from telethon.network import ConnectionTcpAbridged
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest
import config


async def post(session_filename, account, chat, post, proxy):
        client = TelegramClient(
            session=session_filename,
            api_id=account.app_id,
            api_hash=account.app_hash,
            proxy={
                'proxy_type': ProxyType.SOCKS5,
                'addr': proxy.host,
                'port': proxy.port,
                'username': proxy.login,
                'password': proxy.password
            },
            device_model=account.device_model,
            system_version=account.system_version,
            app_version=account.app_version,
            lang_code=account.lang_code,
            timeout=15, request_retries=3, connection_retries=3, retry_delay=5, auto_reconnect=False,
            connection=ConnectionTcpAbridged
        )

        if not client.is_connected():
            try:
                await client.connect()
            except ConnectionError:
                return
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            return

        try:
            await client(JoinChannelRequest(chat.username))
        except rpcerrorlist.UserDeactivatedBanError:
            return

        try:
            channel = await client.get_entity(chat.username)
            msg = await client.forward_messages(
                entity=channel, messages=post.message_id, from_peer=config['postStorage']['username'],
                drop_author=True)
        except rpcerrorlist.UserDeactivatedBanError:
            return

        return msg

account.app_id, account.app_hash, account.device_model, account.system_version, account.app_version, account.lang_code
fields are taken from .json file.
Initialized client does join chats and does forward messages dropping author as required, yet in best case after 2-3 joined chats and 7 forwarded messages session gets deauthorized - another call of post function returns on:
if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            return

What is the cause? I have tested this with ~4 different proxy providers, I got ~70 different telethon sessions deauthorized, I tried all solutions I could think of, yet with no success.
How do I solve this issue? What do I do so that my sessions live long and don`t get deauthorized?
